# Java execute code only after ForkJoinPool submit

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, parallel-processing, forkjoinpool

I have 1 parallel processing code using **ForkJoinPool**:

```
ForkJoinPool customThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
customThreadPool.submit(() -> {
    list.parallelStream().forEach(this::process);
});
```

I am invoking this though some controller. This code runs asynchronously so, controller response will be immediate and async process will happen in background.

Now I want to trigger some another processing once above all the process completes.
Is there any way or method which executes only after completing ForkJoinPool submit.

I tried **submit.isDone** and **submit.isCompletedNormally** but this runs immediate not after completion of submit.

Comment: You should work with `Future`s, more particular with `CompletableFuture`. Then you can do `thenApply(...)` and similar to chain commands.

Comment: `submit` returns a `ForkJoinTask` which is a `Future`; calling `.get()` on it will wait until the result is ready and give it to you. Note that `get()` is blocking!

Comment: If you want to “trigger some another processing once above all the process completes”, you don’t need to wait for completion. You can use, e.g. `CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> list.parallelStream().forEach(this::process), customThreadPool) .whenCompleteAsync((value,throwable) -> …, customThreadPool);` to specify what to do afterwards. Of course, you can also use the good old block to perform one statement after the other, `customThreadPool.submit(() -> { list.parallelStream().forEach(this::process); /* place other statements here */ });`

Comment: @Holger I do not want to execute on each iteration, once everything accomplishes through ForkJoinPool I want to trigger some other processing which is dependent of previous processing.

Comment: Hi @Holger
Sorry I misunderstood your suggestion. Your suggestion also working fine.
Thank you.

Comment: @Holger Is it possible to limit the number of ForkJoinPool and workers in parallel stream? Sometimes it creates so many threads that it's stucking up and not executing continuously.

Comment: A `ForkJoinPool` doesn’t have a thread limit but a configured target parallelism. When a worker thread is about to get blocked, e.g. by calling `join()` on a `CompletableFuture`, the pool will start a new compensation thread to keep up the configured parallelism. That works well, if happening only occasionally but can get out of hand if you’re using blocking calls like `join` or `get` a lot. The conclusion is to avoid blocking calls and use chaining method like `then…` or `whenComplete[Async]` etc. whenever possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `submit` method returns a `Future` which you need to wait on. So you call `get` on it. I think some code like this will work in your case

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        List<String> list = List.of("a", "b", "c");
        ForkJoinPool customThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
        customThreadPool.submit(() -> {
            list.parallelStream().forEach(Scratch::process);
        }).get();
        customThreadPool.submit(() -> System.out.println("done"));

    }

    private static void process(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

It prints

```
b
a
c
done
```

Note the order of a, b, c is not deterministic but done will always be last

Comment: Seems it's working. Thank you

Comment: If your happy could you make it the accepted answer?